# Why NodeMCU crashes with no error after boot with this code?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

My ESP8266 keeps restarting.

This is my init.lua:

```
cfg={}
cfg.ssid="Sensor"
cfg.auth=AUTH_OPEN
wifi.ap.config(cfg)
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.getap(function(t)
    available_aps = "" 
    if t then 
        for k,v in pairs(t) do 
            ap = string.format("%-10s",k) 
            ap = trim(ap)
            available_aps = available_aps .. "<option value='".. ap .."'>".. ap .."</option>"
        end 
        setup_server(available_aps)
    end
end)

function setup_server(aps)
    wifi.setmode(wifi.SOFTAP)
    srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
    srv:listen(80,function(client) 
        client:on("receive",function(client,request)
            wifi.sta.getap(function(t)
                available_aps = "" 
                if t then 
                    for k,v in pairs(t) do 
                        ap = string.format("%-10s",k) 
                        ap = trim(ap)
                        available_aps = available_aps .. "<option value='".. ap .."'>".. ap .."</option>"
                    end 
                end
            end)
            local buf = "";
            local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
            if(method == nil)then
                _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
            end
            local _GET = {}
            if (vars ~= nil)then
                for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
                    _GET[k] = v
                end
            end
            buf = "<html><body>"
            buf = buf .. "<h3>Config</h3><br>"
            buf = buf .. "<form method='get' action='http://" .. wifi.ap.getip() .."'>"
            buf = buf .. "Select access point: <select name='ap'>" .. available_aps .. "</select><br>"
            buf = buf .. "Enter wifi password: <input type='password' name='psw'></input><br>"
            buf = buf .. "Server-IP: <input name='ipTCP' value='192.168.178.1'></input><br>"
            buf = buf .. "<br><button type='submit'>Save</button>"
            buf = buf .. "</form></body></html>"
            local _on,_off = "",""
            if(_GET.pin == "ON1")then
                  buf = buf.."NICE";
            elseif(_GET.pin == "OFF1")then
                  gpio.write(led1, gpio.LOW);
            elseif(_GET.pin == "ON2")then
                  gpio.write(led2, gpio.HIGH);
            elseif(_GET.pin == "OFF2")then
                  gpio.write(led2, gpio.LOW);
            end
            client:send(buf);
            client:close();
            collectgarbage();
        end) 
    end)
end
```

Why it crashes every time after reboot?

How can I troubleshoot this?

I have NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20150318 powered by Lua 5.1.4.

Another lua scripts are running ok.

Comment: NodeMCU 0.9.5 is really really old, try with a recent firmware build from http://nodemcu-build.com. You can't expect us to spot the error right away in that long code sample without an further hints. I'm sure you get some error messages when it crashes? Try to eliminate code step by step until you're down to the few lines that cause the error.

Comment: The problem has been solved but thanks for pointing out that I have old version of nodemcu.

Comment: Don't use 0.95.  Don't do the `client:close()` in the `on('receive')`.  It needs to go in an `on('sent')` cb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same function within client:on("receive",function(client,request).
It's not supposed to be here.

Answer (score 0):

1. I didn't see a call to wifi.sta.connect()
2. Strings are immutable so each time you reassign buf, you create a new one.  Yes the GC will clean it up, if you don't run out first.
3. You can't call client:send() and client:close() back to back... well, you can but it won't work very well.  I'd also worry about sending all of that in one call.
4. Even though they don't accept callbacks the wifi config and connect routines do need to run asynchronously, call them with a timer, then check status before continuing.

The first item is a show-stopper, the others may cause outright failure or may be intermittent.